# Facebook like update status for wordpress

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to wordpress and i am learning a lot. But i am making this intranet site and i need to make a form just like Facebook's update status where my logged in users will need to update their status or upload some images with a description on it. Then underneath that, i will need to have a comment section and like buttons.

I know i could use the create post form on the front page but the status won't be having a title. Attached is an image just to show what i am trying to achieve. Any ideas will be appreciated.[image: This is a diagram of what i am trying to achieve]

Comment: Try BuddyPress they provide all the functionality according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @RaviKumar BuddyPress worked perfectly along side activity plus plugin. Now i need to figure out how to call the activty on a my static page home.php in my theme. I can see the activity if i do a /activity on my site. Any ideas on how i can achieve this? is there a short code for this that i can use? many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Buddypress plugin allows your users to have a profile and create status posts (Facebook style updates) . It's a very popular and free plugin to use. It appears when going to the Add Plugins page in the Admin area.

To add more functionality they're lots of plugins that play well with Buddypress  but not all do. I would keep that in mind when adding additional plugins to your site.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Automattic's P2 theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/p2/), which also supports [post formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) (status is a type of post format)

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid plugin doing this: Status from WPMUDEV

https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/quick-status/